# Sometimes $http status 0 but on django the status is 200

Tags: android, angularjs, django, cordova, ionic-framework

Firstly, sorry about my english; I am not a native speaker.

Secondly, I'm making an app for Android using the framework Ionic and I'm using Django as an REST API.

I have issues with a factory: the HTTP status from the request in Django is 200 and the database registers the change, but in the app the HTTP status is 0. This happens only in this factory that contains two POST requests. The other POST requests made on the other factories work fine.

To test the app I use Google Chrome (with the command `--disable-web-security`), Ionic version 1.5.0, Django version 1.8.2, Cordova version 5.0 (I couldn't find which version of AngularJS I'm using). I have the same issues on several mobile devices.

Here are 3 controllers that cause the problem:

```
.controller('PlanesCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicPopup,$location, Planes, $window) {   

$scope.planes = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['planes']);
$scope.usuario = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['user']);
        var usuario_id = {
            codusuario: $scope.usuario["codusuario"]
        };
$scope.mascotaEscogida = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['mascotaEscogida']);
        var especie_id = {
            codespecie: $scope.mascotaEscogida.codespecie
        };
        var mascota_id = {
            codmascota: $scope.mascotaEscogida.id
        };
        var data = {
            codespecie: $scope.mascotaEscogida.codespecie,
            codmascota: $scope.mascotaEscogida.id
        }

$scope.ver_plan = function(plan){
    Planes.selectChosenPlan(plan.id);
    if (plan.suscrito == 0){
        $location.path("/app/planes/" + plan.id); 
    }
    else{
        $location.path("/app/entrenar/" + plan.id);  
    }
};
})

.controller('PlanCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal,$location, $ionicPopup, $window, Planes) { 
$scope.mascotaEscogida = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['mascotaEscogida']);

var mascota_id = {
            codmascota: $scope.mascotaEscogida.codmascota
        };
$scope.plan = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['planActual']);

var data = {
            codplan: $scope.plan.id,
            codespecie: $scope.mascotaEscogida.codespecie,
            codmascota: $scope.mascotaEscogida.id
        };

$scope.suscribir = function(){
  var data = {
            codplan: $scope.plan.id,
            codespecie: $scope.mascotaEscogida.codespecie,
            codmascota: $scope.mascotaEscogida.id
        };
console.log($scope.plan.id);
console.log($scope.mascotaEscogida.codespecie);
console.log($scope.mascotaEscogida.id);
Planes.suscribir(data, function() {
        alert("Su mascota ha sido suscrita al plan con éxito");
        } , function() {
        } , function() {
            console.log("No funciona suscribir en funcion suscribir, PlanCtrl");
        });
Planes.buscar(data, function() {
        } , function() {
        } , function() {
            console.log("No funciona buscar en funcion suscribir, PlanCtrl");
        });
$location.path("/app/pet/" + mascota_id);
$window.location.reload(true);
};
})

.controller('PetCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $filter, $location, Mascota, Planes, $window, $ionicModal) {

$scope.mascotaEscogida = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['mascotaEscogida']);
$scope.usuario_logged = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['user_data']);
$scope.usuario_info = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['user']);
        var data = {
            codespecie: $scope.mascotaEscogida.codespecie,
            codmascota: $scope.mascotaEscogida.id
        }

$scope.ver_entrenamientos = function(mascota){
Planes.buscar(data, function() {
        alert("Planes encontrados con exito");
        } , function() {
            alert("La mascotas no posee especie registrada (esto es muy extraño)");
        } , function() {
            console.log("No funciona buscar en ver_entrenamientos, PetCtrl");   
        });
$location.path("/app/planes");
$window.location.reload(true);
};

if($scope.usuario_logged === false) {
    $location.path('/login');
}

else {

  $scope.test = function() {
    fecha_hora = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '-0300');
    var info = {
      fecha: fecha_hora,
      codmascota: $scope.mascotaEscogida.id,
      codusuario: $scope.usuario_info.codusuario
    }
  Mascota.alimentar(info, function() {
    alert("La mascota ha sido alimentada con exito :)");
  } , function() {
    alert("Lo sentimos, algo ha ocurrido y no podemos registrar la alimentación");
  } , function() {
    alert("Verifica la conexión a internet");
  });
}
}

})
```

And here is the factory:

```
 .factory("Planes", function($http, $window){
    var url = "http://localhost:8000/plan/";

    var currentPlanes = function(data){
        $window.localStorage['planes'] = JSON.stringify(data);    
    };

    return {

        selectChosenPlan: function(id) {
            var arregloPlanes = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['planes']);
            for (var i = 0; i <= arregloPlanes.length - 1; i++) {
                if (parseInt(arregloPlanes[i].id) == id) {
                    $window.localStorage['planActual'] = JSON.stringify(arregloPlanes[i]);
                }
            }
        },

        buscar: function(inf, successFunction, errorFunction, connectionError) {
            $http({ 
                method: 'POST',
                url: url + 'planes/',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                data: JSON.stringify(inf),
                timeout: 20000 
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                if (response.data.length > 0) {
                    console.log("buscar" + response.data[0]);
                    currentPlanes(response.data);
                    successFunction();
                }
                else{ 
                    currentPlanes(response.data);
                    errorFunction();
                }
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                connectionError();
            });
        },


        suscribir: function(inf, successFunction, errorFunction, connectionError) {
            $http({ 
                method: 'POST',
                url: url + 'suscribir/',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                data: JSON.stringify(inf),
                timeout: 20000 
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                if (response.data.length > 0) {
                    console.log("suscribir" + response.data[0]);
                    currentPlanes(response.data);
                    successFunction();
                }
                else{ 
                    currentPlanes(response.data);
                    errorFunction();
                }
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                connectionError();
            });
        }
    };    
})
```

I've made some research in the internet, but all the solutions I've found point to the CORS. If that were the problem, the other factory wouldn't work either, so I don't think that's the problem. Some other answers say that the problem could be in the HTML, on the button that calls `'ver_plan'` or   `'ver_entrenamiento'`, but both are set with  `type="button"`, so the submit wasn't the problem either. The error happens randomly and I can't find the issue in the flow of events. Sometimes, I even get a  `'broken pipe'`  message from Django, but this also happens randomly.

I know that the JSON answer is valid and has the correct format; I'm out of ideas and I need to solve these issues.

Edit: Also, the line `console.log("No funciona buscar en funcion suscribir, PlanCtrl");` doesn't appear in the console when I get the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer a couple of weeks ago. The problem was 
`$window.location.reload(true);` and `$location.path();`

It is not necessary the line `$window.location.reload(true);` if `$location.path();` is located inside the factory call. For example:

```
Planes.buscar(data, function() {
    $location.path("/app/pet/" + mascota_id);
    } , function() {
    } , function() {
        console.log("No funciona buscar en funcion suscribir, PlanCtrl");
    });
```

This way, the redirection occurs only if the answer from the server was successful and there is no need to use `$window.location.reload(true);`

I wish I can give you more details about the reason of the problem but my english is not good enough.